# How to tell TypeScript to understand that using array.some() in an if clause already narrows type?

Tags: typescript, if-statement, type-narrowing

I have this code:

```
const list = ['a', 'b', '= c', 'd']
if (list.some(element => element.includes('='))) {
    const elementWithEqualSign = list.find(element => element.includes('='))
}
```

In here `elementWithEqualSign` has type `string | undefined`, while in fact it should be only `string`, due to the condition above filtering the possibility of `undefined`. Is there a way to tell it to automatically narrow the type without using [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `as string`? I suppose the answer is somewhere in [TypeScript: Documentation - Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), but I don't know to find it out.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, no.

Consider the situation where you use a different condition in the `.some()` from the one in `.find()`.

How would the compiler figure out (automatically) that the first condition does/does not change the return type of `.find()`.

What if the condition is arbitrarily complicated? What if, for example, it checked each element against a REST API? Even with an apparently identical condition, it could return a different result the second time (this is sometimes referred to as time-of-check-time-of-use -- TOCTOU), meaning that `undefined` *is* a possible type.

Use a type assertion.

Comment: what if I use the same callback, and it has only one type for the output?

Comment: Type assertion _or_ non-null assertion operator: `const elementWithEqualSign = list.find(element => element.includes('='))!;`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay don't do this but
https://tsplay.dev/mLJBZw

```
interface Array<T> {
  // make "some" to say it has the item
  some<V>(predicate: (v: T) => v is T & V): this is { guaranteedHas: V };
  // make "find" to get the item if it has it
  find<V>(this: { guaranteedHas: V }, predicate: (v: T) => v is T & V): V;
}
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  // make "some" to say it has the item
  some<V>(predicate: (v: T) => v is T & V): this is { guaranteedHas: V };
  // make "find" to get the item if it has it
  find<V>(this: { guaranteedHas: V }, predicate: (v: T) => v is T & V): V;
}
interface String {
  // this is a "proper" typing, but...
  includes<T, V extends string>(this: T, searchString: V): this is T & `${string}${V}${string}`;
}

function includes<D extends string>(d: D) {
  // ...but you need a wrapper because `is` returns become booleans
  return function inc<S extends string>(s: S): s is S & `${string}${D}${string}` {
    return s.includes(d)
  }
}

const list = ['a', 'b', '= c', 'd'] as const
if (list.some(includes('='))) {
  const elementWithEqualSign = list.find(includes('='))
  //    ^?
  // const elementWithEqualSign: "= c"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why go through the array twice with the same test? Use `find` for both:

```
const elementWithEqualSign = list.find(element => element.includes('='));

if (elementWithEqualSign) {
// elementWithEqualSign is a string here
}
```

Comment: when I use the same idea but for regex strings, I was taught that `test()` runs much quicker than `match()`. So while you can use the result of `match` for the condition clause, having them separate is advisable. I apply that notion here

Comment: @Ooker for `find` vs `some`, the differences in performance seem negligible: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/12534/0/arrayfind-vs-arraysome

Comment: when do things start innegligible? Because if it's really negligible, then we won't need to use `some()` at all, right?